# C# Selenium how can I implement click on button without id

Tags: c#, selenium

C# Selenium how can I implement click on button without id

Here is the html:

```
<div class="fe-margin"> 
  <button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: $root.addParameter, enable: $root.selectedParameter() == null" type="button"/>
  Add parameter button
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can do. Using class name of xpath you can perform click action.

Ex:

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("AddContentBTN")).Click();
```

Comment: I tried this "//input[@value='Add parameter']" did not work.

Comment: please try using class name.

Answer (score 6):

`Selenium` offers various searcg options to find an element. Check the [`documentation`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn@6239/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/index.html) for more details.

These are the widely used search options.

- ClassName
- CssSelector
- Id
- LinkText
- Name
- PartialLinkText
- TagName
- XPath

**Usage :**

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn-default")); // works for your case.
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("closeButton"));
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='menu_bg']/ul/li[3]"));
var element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#import>a"));
```

Once you get the element using any of the selectors, you just need to perform `Click` on it.

```
element.Click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. The issue I see is that the page is long and the button is further down. I am getting this error System.InvalidOperationException: Element is not clickable at point (139.5, 175). Other element would receive the click: <div class="container"></div> Looks like I need to scroll down to get the focus.

Answer (score 4):

**Try this Xpath -**

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class ='btn btn-default']"));

element.Click();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can click on buttons that aren't visible using JavaScript

```
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", ElementToClick)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by `ClassName` with one of the classes

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn-default")).Click();
// or
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn")).Click();
```

Or by `CssSelector` with both classes

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".btn.btn-default")).Click();
```

> Edit

The error

> Element is not clickable at point

means Selenium can't see the button, so it can't click on it. You need to scroll to it first

```
IWebElement button = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn-default")); // locate the button, can be done with any other selector
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(button).Perform(); // move to the button
button.Click();
```

Comment: I am getting this error when trying these. Any idea whats going on? System.InvalidOperationException: Element is not clickable at point (139.5, 175). Other element would receive the click: <div class="container"></div>

Comment: Tried the updated answer, I see that it identifies the element but does not move to the element and so it fails again with the same error. Is there some other way to scroll down to that element to perform the click

Comment: @SteelBird82 You can scroll with JavaScript `IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;`
            `js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", button);`

Comment: `button` is the WebElement you located earlier,

Answer (score 1):

You can use button name or text:

```cs
driver.FindElements(by.TagName("button")).FirstOrDefault(ele=>ele.GetAttribute("Name").Equals("Submit")).click();
```

or, case-sensitive:

```cs
driver.FindElements(by.TagName("button")).FirstOrDefault(ele=>ele.GetAttribute("Name").ToLower().Equals("Submit")).click();
```

or, in your case:

```cs
driver.FindElements(by.TagName("button")).FirstOrDefault(ele=>ele.Text.Equals("Name").Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this XPath to find your button by text:

```
"//div[normalize-space(.)='Add parameter button']/button"
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided here offer most of the ways you can do this job. That is by the selection classes Selenium provides and 'manually' with JavaScript. Occasionally I ran into weird implementations of buttons and menus where none of these methods worked for me. What I did then was move the mouse over the button and shoot a free click. Selenium provides a way to do it:

```
Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
action.MoveToElement(/IWebElement here/).Perform();
action.Click();   
   or
action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter).Perform();
```

If this fails as well my last card to play would be image recognition lib,
like the some of the c# wrapped Sikuli packages on github.

Answer (score 0):

`IWebElement btn = Firefox.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn"));
 btn.Click();`

This should do it.
I found that using a part of the ClassName does the job.